# Animate wpf control in a for loop

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard

I am trying to implement an animation where I move my control from one row to another using for loop.

```
    private void AnimateStoryBoard(int number)
    {
        Storyboard _currentStoryBoard = new Storyboard();

       //Row Animation
        Int32Animation newrowanimation = new Int32Animation();
        newrowanimation.From = number;
        newrowanimation.To = number+1;
        newrowanimation.Duration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 500);

        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(newrowanimation, new PropertyPath("(Grid.Row)"));

        _currentStoryBoard.Children.Add(newrowanimation);

        Storyboard.SetTarget(newrowanimation, myrectangle);

        _currentStoryBoard.Begin();
    }
```

and I am calling it using

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            AnimateStoryBoard(i);
        }
```

Now when I run this I want the animation to go from 1 to 2 then 2 to 3 then 3 to 4...9-10. However the animation directly skips to 9 and then 10.

Also how can I do this in XAML?,and please note that the number 10 here is just an example.The number has to come from code-behind and it will keep changing.

Comment: Yo don't wait for the previous animations to be finished prior to starting the next animation. This leaves the last animation to be in place. You should wait for the animations to be finished within the loop

Comment: This appears to be an exact duplicate of the question you asked previously: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44212995/repeating-storyboard-animation-using-for-loop. Do not delete and repost questions. **Fix the question you posted originally.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO there is no need to reinvent the wheel: [key frame animation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742524(v=vs.110).aspx) are meant also for this purpose.

So, for creating the animation that you need, you can use something like:

```
Storyboard storyBoard = new Storyboard();
int gridRowLimit = 5; // here you can set how many rows your grid has

Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames intKeyFrame = new Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames();
intKeyFrame.Duration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, gridRowLimit * 500);

for (int i = 1; i < gridRowLimit; i++)
{
    intKeyFrame.KeyFrames.Add(new DiscreteInt32KeyFrame(i));
}

Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(intKeyFrame, new PropertyPath("(Grid.Row)"));
Storyboard.SetTarget(intKeyFrame, yourControl);

storyBoard.Children.Add(intKeyFrame);
storyBoard.Begin();
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Just what I wanted..Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As Alexander Clare mentioned in the comments, you have to setup several animations in a storyboard. Your solution using a loop does not work because your method won't return while running the loop and thus the UI Thread won't be able to render the changes that the storyboard / animations caused.

One solution would be a single `Storyboard` instance with a variable number of animations in it (one animation per row). Use the `BeginTime` property to stagger the animations. I would suggest that you use a value from 40ms to 100ms between these animations (I wouldn't go below 20ms).

In code, this would look something like this:

```
private void AnimateStoryboard(int number)
{
    // Create the storyboard that will be played
    var storyboard = new Storyboard();

    // Create the animation objects for each row change and add them to the storyboard
    var currentBeginTime = TimeSpan.Zero;
    for (var i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        var animation = new Int32Animation();
        // Set all the properties that you set on your animation objects before, and additionally use BeginTime
        animation.BeginTime = currentBeginTime;
        storyboard.Children.Add(animation);

        // Update the currentBeginTime to achieve the staggering effect
        currentBeginTime += TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50);
    }

    // Finally, start the Storyboard to run all animations
    storyboard.Begin();

}
```